# How to redirect to a gatsby-react page with an onclick event of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to redirect to a page using an `onClick` event of a component. As I have react gatsby installation is it possible to use `Link` from `gatsby-link` to redirect.

```
import React from  'react';
import { OverflowMenu, OverflowMenuItem } from '../Overflow';
import Link from 'gatsby-theme-carbon/src/components/Link';

class  OverflowComponent extends React.Component {

editPage(index) {
  console.log();
  // window.location.href='/edit';
  return(
    <Link to="/edit"></Link> // I'm trying to redirect to Edit page
  )
}

deletePage() {
  console.log("Delete clicked");
}

  render(){ 
    return (
      <div>
        <OverflowMenu flipped={true}>
            <OverflowMenuItem  itemText="Edit" primaryFocus onClick={() => this.editPage()} />
            <OverflowMenuItem  itemText="Delete" onClick={() => this.deletePaget()} />
        </OverflowMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OverflowComponent;
```

from the above code the `Overflow` component is a contributed component and it can have a onClick function. And I'm trying to redirect using gatsby-link.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of using Link or window.location as mentioned in the question we can use `navigate` from `gatsby`. As shown below

```
import React from  'react';
import { OverflowMenu, OverflowMenuItem } from '../Overflow';
import {navigate} from 'gatsby'; //import navigate from gatsby

class  OverflowComponent extends React.Component {

editPage(index) {
  navigate('/edit'); //navigate to edit page
}

deletePage() {
  console.log("Delete clicked");
}

  render(){ 
    return (
      <div>
        <OverflowMenu flipped={true}>
            <OverflowMenuItem  itemText="Edit" primaryFocus onClick={() => this.editPage()} />
            <OverflowMenuItem  itemText="Delete" onClick={() => this.deletePaget()} />
        </OverflowMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OverflowComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Link>` renders an anchor element (`<a href='...'>`). You would probably want to use `navigate` here instead: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function.

You might also need to use the onClick prop on the `<OverflowMenuItem>` component depending on how you have that setup.